# For a dictionary inside another dictionary how do you sort it by the value and compare different items within the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to create a function that applies a promotion to a basket (like a supermarket), each item in the basket has a group number so certain items can have the promotion applied say for example my basket dictionary is:

```
basket = { 
'10015' : {
        'name' : 'Diced Beef 400G',
        'price' : 4.50,
        'unit' : 'pieces', 
        'promotion' : 'get4pay3',
        'group' : 4,
        'amount' : 5,
 },
 '10017' : {
        'name' : 'Brisket Beef 400G',
        'price' : 3.50,
        'unit' : 'pieces', 
        'promotion' : 'get4pay3',
        'group' : 4,
        'amount' : 3,
 },
...
}
```

How do you compare each item in the dictionary i.e. another item might have a different group number for the promotion. And how do you sort the dictionary by price? so the promotion is applied to the cheapest item.

currently I have

```
amount = 0
for ident in basket:
if basket[ident]['group']==4:
    amount = amount + basket[ident]['amount']

amountPayable = amount - amount//4
```

Thanks

Comment: As much as I know you can't sort dictionaries, as members of them are sorted by their keys (In your case by their group numbers). You can sort lists however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have written the original code with generator expression that returns all the products where `group == 4`:

```
sum(v['amount'] for v in basket.values() if v['group'] == 4) # 8
```

As comments mentioned dictionaries aren't ordered so you can't sort them. That said you can sort the values in the dictionary to a list:

```
s = sorted(basket.values(), key=lambda x: x['price'])
s[0] # {'group': 4, 'name': 'Brisket Beef 400G', 'price': 3.5, 'amount': 3, 'promotion': 'get4pay3', 'unit': 'pieces'}
```

Note that if you just need the cheapest product you don't have to sort the values:

```
min(basket.values(), key=lambda x: x['price']) # {'group': 4, 'name': 'Brisket Beef 400G', 'price': 3.5, 'amount': 3, 'promotion': 'get4pay3', 'unit': 'pieces'}
```

Comment: when I use it I get the error 'AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'intervals''

Comment: @JasmineNisic: Didn't initially notice [tag:python-3.x] in the question, I've changed the examples accordingly.